# "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" error whem unit testing redux action with axios and moxios

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am trying to test an async redux action that makes an api call with axios. I am testing it with the help of moxios and it worked a couple of days ago but for some reason today when i created another async action it just broke.

Here is my unit test code:

```
  1 import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
  2 import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
  3 import moxios from 'moxios';
  4
  5 import * as types from '../../../../client/auth/actions/action_types';
  6 import loginAuth from '../../../../client/auth/actions/login_action';
  7
  8 require('dotenv').config();
  9 const expect = require('chai').expect;
 10
 11 const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);
 12
 13 const user = {
 14   email: 'john@loginActionTest.com',
 15   password: 'secret',
 16 };
 17
 18 describe('authAction -> loginUser() ', () => {
 19   beforeEach(() => {
 20     moxios.install();
 21   });
 22
 23   afterEach(() => {
 24     moxios.uninstall();
 25   });
 26
 27   it('should create AUTH_SUCCESS when finishes without error', () => {
 28     const store = mockStore({});
 29     const token = 'authToken';
 30     const expectedActions = [
 31       { type: types.AUTH_REQUEST },
 32       { type: types.AUTH_SUCCESS, token },
 33     ];
 34
 35     moxios.wait(() => {
 36       const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
 37       request.respondWith({
 38         status: 200,
 39         response: { success: true, token },
 40       });
 41     });
 42
 43     return store.dispatch(loginAuth(user)).then(() => {
 44       expect(store.getActions()).to.deep.equal(expectedActions);
 45     });
 46   });
```

Here is my action creator:

```
  1 /* @flow */
  2 import axios from 'axios';
  3 import {
  4   authRequest,
  5   authSuccess,
  6   authError,
  7 } from './auth_actions';
  8
  9 function loginAuth(user: { email: string, password: string }) {
 10   return function (dispatch: any) {
 11     dispatch(authRequest());
 12
 13     return axios.post('/api/auth/login', {
 14       email: user.email,
 15       password: user.password,
 16     })
 17     .then((response: any) => {
 18       dispatch(authSuccess(response.data.token));
 19     })
 20     .catch((error: any) => {
 21       dispatch(authError(error.response.data.messages));
 22     });
 23   };
 24 }
 25
 26 export default loginAuth;
```

Here is my mocha error message:

```
authAction -> loginUser()  should create AUTH_SUCCESS when finishes without error:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
      at client/auth/actions/login_action.js:21:26
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong and how to fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to fix it however I still don't know what caused it. This error happened at the same time [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193934/cannot-read-property-push-of-undefined-error-when-testing-redux-action-that) happened. When I commented out the line `browserHistory.push()` in redux action creators all the tests passed. Hope this helps anyone.